# Use redis with externally hosted Mysql

Tags: apache2, redis

I have an Apache2 (aws ec2) based server and just installed Redis However when I try to start Redis I get the below error and not sure how to fix it so that Redis can be started? I believe it is because the server doesnt have Mysql installed on it as i use an external Mysql database (aws rds). So should install mysql on the ec2 specificly for redis to use or should I /How do I install Redis to use my externally hosted mysql?

```
 oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=3154, just started
 3154:C 14 May 13:20:26.937 # Configuration loaded
 3154:C 14 May 13:20:26.937 # systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
 3154:M 14 May 13:20:26.937 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
 3154:M 14 May 13:20:26.937 # Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
 3154:M 14 May 13:20:26.937 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.

 3154:M 14 May 13:20:26.938 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
 3154:M 14 May 13:20:26.938 # Server initialized
 3154:M 14 May 13:20:26.938 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sy
 3154:M 14 May 13:20:26.938 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
 3154:M 14 May 13:20:26.938 * Ready to accept connections
```

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that this is an issue with MySQL missing? What you got are warnings anyway, not errors (`Ready to accept connections`).

Comment: I know it says "Ready to accept connections" just wasnt sure about the warnings because the tutorial I followed didnt show these warnings and then in trying to fix the warnings I had saw something about redis using Mysql so thought oh maybe thats whats causing the warnings.

Comment: Redis does not even use MySQL. But there are ten bad tutorials on the Internet for every good one. As for the warnings, what Linux distribution is this?